# Value of sys.path differs between windows and linux when setting up a virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-venv

When creating a virtual environment via `python -m venv .venv` and then activating this environment I notice that on Windows the root directory of the environment is part of the import path as reported by `sys.path` but for linux it's not.

Python version: `3.8.2`

Example:

```
python -m venv .venv
```

On Windows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'c:\\temp\\.venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36', 'c:\\temp\\.venv', 'c:\\temp\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> sys.prefix
'c:\\temp\\.venv'
```

Notice the entry `c:\\temp\\.venv` in the path.

On Linux:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/carsten/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>> sys.prefix
'/carsten/.venv'
```

Notice that the root of the environment is NOT part of the  path.

Is this difference by design or is this a bug?

Comment: @ErykSun, I looked inside `C:\temp\.venv`, but didn't find how `C:\temp\.venv` gets into sys.path.

Comment: @ErykSun, no. For example, I looked in `activate.bat` but didn't find anything which puts `C:\temp\.venv` into sys.path. Not sure if I expressed clearly

Comment: @Philippe,  it's the normal interpreter startup sequence that imports the site module. Run with `-S` to skip importing site.py, and you will no longer see the venv prefix directory in the list. In the current site.py, `addsitepackages` calls [`getsitepackages`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5cc2089cc354469f12eabc7ba54280e85fdd6dc/Lib/site.py#L319), for which if the path separator is backslash (a weird way to identify Windows given the better ways available), it first adds `prefix` and then `os.path.join(prefix, libdir, "site-packages")`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, even though I still do not understand. I guess I need to go through your comments (with different links) in order to fully understand.

Comment: @ErykSun thanks a lot for the explanation and the explanation of the origin of the difference. So it's basically this line https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/site.py#L348

Answer (score 0):

The Windows case also has the installed prefix directory "C:\Python36", which is added by the interpreter startup code, in addition to the venv prefix directory that's added by site.py. Adding these directories is a vestige from long ago. There's no compelling reason that either "C:\Python36" or "C:\temp\.venv" needs to be in `sys.path`. Though someone somewhere is probably depending on it.

Adding the prefix directory used to be productive in early versions of the Windows release back in the 1990s, which initially put standard-library extension modules in the prefix directory instead of a dedicated "DLLs" subdirectory, plus it also used the prefix directory for site packages. For example, see [site.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f30bec7bb2d06da0543d435b1edcb983cbd2801b/Lib/site.py) from 1997-08-09. A few iterations [later](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62b297b698634969d6ce69f14ef3d268c8904a48/Lib/site.py), "site-packages" was added in Unix, but Windows was still using the prefix directory.

Finally, a few years later on [2001-07-12](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6a479f548850f5ccf941eb74f855d6b2dc91368f/Lib/site.py), "site-packages" was added to the Windows release of Python 2.2, but *in addition* to the prefix directory instead of replacing it in `sys.path`. This was proposed by Paul Moore (still an active core developer) in [PEP 250](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0250), who notes that the prefix directory is being retained in order to support .pth files added there.

In the current implementation of site.py, `addsitepackages` calls [`getsitepackages`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5cc2089cc354469f12eabc7ba54280e85fdd6dc/Lib/site.py#L319), for which if the path separator is backslash (a weird way to identify Windows given the better ways available), it first adds `prefix` and then `os.path.join(prefix, libdir, "site-packages")`.